# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I am trying to fix the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined
Navbar
E:/smnd/client/src/components/layout/Navbar.js:7

```
   import { logout } from '../../actions/auth';
   
 const Navbar = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading }, logout }) => {
```

here is my navbar code and I have already defined my isAuthenticated i have defined it in auth.js reducers file .... the middleware is not working properly

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { logout } from '../../actions/auth';

const Navbar = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading }, logout }) => {
  const authLinks = (
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a onClick={logout} href='#!'>
        <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>{' '}
        <span className="hide-sm">Logout</span> 
      </a></li>
      {/* <li>
        <Link to='/profiles'>Developers</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to='/dashboard'>
          <i className='fas fa-user' />{' '}
          <span className='hide-sm'>Dashboard</span>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a onClick={logout} href='#!'>
          <i className='fas fa-sign-out-alt' />{' '}
          <span className='hide-sm'>Logout</span>
        </a>
      </li> */}
    </ul>
  );

  const guestLinks = (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to='#!'>Developers</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <nav className='navbar bg-dark'>
      <h1>
        <Link to='/'>
          <i className='fas fa-code' /> DevConnector
        </Link>
      </h1>
      {!loading && (
        <Fragment>{isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}</Fragment>
      )}
    </nav>
  );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {
  logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logout }
)(Navbar);
```

Comment: You could set a default value for the `auth` param: `const Navbar = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading } = { isAuthenticated: false, loading: false }, logout }) =>`